# Using FOSRestBundle to return large table with +100K rows

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

FOSRestBundle is working fine but whenever I try to return large JSONArray with 50,000 records or more the client takes more than 5 minutes and timeout.

This is my controller

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;

class ProductController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface {

    public function cgetAction(){
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyApiBundle:Product')->findAll();
        $view = $this->view($data);
        return $this->handleView($view);            
    }
}
```

and this is my config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'        
        default_engine: php
```

Update 1: Whenever I remove the relationship from the entity everything work fine.

Comment: Return fewer records?  Seriously, php is not really the best solution for transferring huge datasets.  Consider using pagination.

Answer (score 1):

If your provide visual data to your customer it just does not make sense to return more than a readable amount of records. You always want to paginate the data on client and server side to limit the load.

Comment: I'm using it to sync the server database with the client database.

Comment: @mghazal hm what kind of database are you using?? I would consider using replication. E.g. if you are using mongodb http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/ or mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html instead of syncing manually